# Compiler error in VBA Excel while running a code using POST method

Tags: api, excel, post, vba

User - defined type not defined- Compiler error in the following 3 lines of my code:

```
Dim Client As New WebClient
......
Dim Request As New WebRequest
......
Dim Response As WebResponse
```

I have tried using the Microsoft WinHTTP Services,version 5.1 reference also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using [VBA-Web](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web) (yay!), you'll need to install it by downloading the [most recent release](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web/releases) and importing the modules/classes from `src` or running `VBA-Web - Installer.xlsm` to import them automatically.